# Using .Net MVC5, how to return foreign text in a JsonResult Action via jQuery.ajax and/or Ajax.Helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

Lets say I have an **CONTROLLER Action** like this (for demonstration only):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetMessage (PageViewModel vmodel)
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    Response.Headers[Constants.Messages] = 
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            new string[] { "ČČŠŠĆĆćććppššččđđ" });
    return null;
}
```

And a client side **jQuery ajax** method like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetMessage","Test")',
    method: "POST",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("Success!");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status + " | " + error);
        alert(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
});
```

Why does my alert always shows my **custom header** with value like this:

```
["ÄÄÅ Å ÄÄÄÄÄppÅ¡Å¡ÄÄÄÄ"]
```

I tried setting the Response.Encoding to:

```
null, "ISO-8859-2", "ANSI"
```

also, tried to change **Response.ContentType** to:

```
"text/html", "application/json"
```

But for some reason when I print all headers **content type** part looks like this:

```
"content-type=text/html; charset=utf-8;"
```

If I return my messages like this:

```
return Json(new string[] { "ČČŠŠĆĆćććppššččđđ" });
```

everything is fine **BUT** it looks like mobile browsers discard the responseText and put default status message which in my case is "Bad Request" (tried it on Galaxy Tab A T-280, Sony M5, iPhone 6)

Any ideas on how to solve this? ... or alternative way to return data on a http error response?

**UPDATE 1**

It seems I've been using `Response.Encoding` to try and set up a encoding for response but since I'm using headers I should have been using `Response.HeaderEncoding`.

So according to that, using `Response.HeaderEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2");` should fix my problem but it does not. While I don't know why, using "ISO-8859-1" gives somewhat better results. "ISO-8859-1" converts `Š` to `S` and other chars in question which I'am able to tolerate but its still not a solid fix. Any ideas?